# Use of CPUQuota in systemd

Tags: linux, limit, cpu, fedora, systemd

I am trying to put a hard limit in CPU usage for a dd command . I have created the following unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Virtual Distributed Ethernet

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ddcommand
CPUQuota=10%

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which call the following simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k
```

As I have seen in this guide:
http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html
The CPU usage for my dd service should not exceed the 10%. But when I run the system-cgtop command the usage is about 70-75% .

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

P.S. When I execute `systemctl show dd` I get the following results regarding CPU

```
CPUShares=18446744073709551615
StartupCPUShares=18446744073709551615
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=100ms
LimitCPU=18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Not sayin' this is off-topic per se, but you may have better luck with this on sysadmin-focused sibling site [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thank you I'll try also there.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am using CPUShares as a temporary solution. The problem is that CPUShares does not set a hard limit but works only when there is competition for the CPU usage.

Comment: Do you have a quad core with hyperthyroid enabled? Aka 8 logical cores?  10% of 800% is 80%.  I'm just speculating but have you tried setting the limit to 1% to see what happens?

Comment: @IyadK this is from the man page: "The percentage specifies how much CPU time the unit shall get at maximum, relative to the total CPU time available on one CPU." The argument is still valid if by 1 CPU they do not mean individual cores, which is what [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html) states: "Note that shares of CPU time are distributed per all CPU cores on multi-core systems"

Comment: @SteveGr2015 CPUShares is just a weight, since default is 1024, any higher value increases its share and vice versa. Similar to nice. It does not limit.

Comment: For reference, the ServerFault question can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/683911/use-of-cpuquota-in-systemd).

Comment: Hello all, @TomKeegasi gave a detailed answer to ServerFault question which I accepted it. You may check there, why this problem probably occurred.

Comment: @TomKeegasi Adding CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH option to my kernel did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally ran across another valid answer given on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213903/linux-cgroups-limit-cpu-usage-in-absolute-values-which-do-not-depend-on-cpu-spe

If you want a hard limit on CPU bandwidth, you can use cpu.cfs_quota_us and cpu.cfs_period_us. From the Kernel's CFS docs:

The bandwidth allowed for a group is specified using a quota and period. Within each given "period" (microseconds), a group is allowed to consume only up to "quota" microseconds of CPU time. When the CPU bandwidth consumption of a group exceeds this limit (for that period), the tasks belonging to its hierarchy will be throttled and are not allowed to run again until the next period.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate ways to limit cpu usage:
1. Use taskset command.
2. Use control groups.
3. Use docker and limit cpu utilization by using cpuset.
4. Reduce the number of threads in the application. Some calculation is required with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could try is run [`cpulimit`](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit) as a daemon.  I have not tested this; it's just an idea.

It's in the ubuntu repos:

```
sudo apt install cpulimit
```

Use systemd if you like.  This should limit *all* instances of dd to 20% CPU.

```
[Unit]
Description=dd CPU Limiter

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cpulimit -e dd -l 20

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/21058/533341)

Answer (score 0):

The option "*CPUQuota=*" depends on the number of CPUs on the system, because it ensures that the executed processes will never get more than the % CPU time on **ONE CPU**; and I think CPU usage % that you get with the cmd system**d**-cgtop is on all CPUs of the system.

Answer (score -2):

Implies "CPUAccounting=true"
So it should be

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ddcommand
CPUAccounting=true
CPUQuota=10%
```

Comment: *Implies* means, that `CPUAccounting=true` is implicitly set and need not be set explicitly.